# compass failing to load singularitygs gem

Tags: sass, compass-sass, singularitygs

Trying to get a new project set up using Singularity.gs but I keep running into a snag with Compass.

First I used Terminal to install the necessary Ruby Gems (sass, compass, singularitygs, respectively).

Next I created a new project using the command:

```
compass create project1 -r singularitygs --using singularitygs
```

In the directory of my choosing.

At this point, in an effort to make life easier I've also attempted to use offerings like Scout (http://mhs.github.io/scout-app/) and/or Compass.app (http://compass.handlino.com/) so I can take advantage of a more user-friendly GUI.

I'm running into problems using either of these apps however, so I'm assuming it has something to do either with my Ruby gem install of singularitygs or with the creation of a new project.

Specifically, once I have a target directory and folder structure in place, I'll attempt to "watch" the sass folder and get an error that looks like:

(Compass)

```
no such file to load -- singularitygs
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1062:in `require'
file:/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/Java/compass-app.jar!/require_patch.rb:6:in `require'
```

or
(Scout)

```
LoadError on line 1038 of org/jruby/RubyKernel.java: no such file to load -- singularitygs
/Applications/Scout.app/Contents/Resources/vendor/gems/gems/compass
0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/data.rb:161:in `require'
```

Strangely enough, I also get a very similar error message in Scout if I try to watch a Sass folder inside of a project that's using Foundation (having also installed the zurb-foundation ruby gem previously)

I am SUPER new to getting Sass / Compass set up so I'm definitely feeling a bit out of my element. I know this is probably not the easiest thing to diagnose from my description, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Hopefully I've managed to describe my issue clearly enough. Bear with me if any of this appears vague or incomplete, definitely not my intention.

Thanks so much.

Comment: What happens if you use `compass watch` from the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apps like Scout and Compass.app come bundled with their own versions of Ruby so even though you installed the gems on your computer they are not installed when compiling from those apps.

Here is how to make Compass.app use the version of Ruby on your computer. Open preferences and check “Custom”. Note your path may be different:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks Scott!  That seems to have done the trick with Compass.app..  FWIW, also happened upon this entry re: Scout  https://github.com/mhs/scout-app/issues/126