# LoadError on line 1038 : no such file to load -- bootstrap-sass

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, compass-sass, compass, adobe-scout

I start my Compass projects in console with line `$ compass create myProject1`
which create a *myProject1* folder with a *config.rb* file and *sass* & *stylesheets* folders.
Next, I use **Scout.app** to watch *myProyect1* and it works.

### For Bootstrap-Compass-Sass projects

I run in console the line `$ compass create myProyect2 -r bootstrap-sass --using bootstrap`
for create a *myProject2* folder with a *config.rb* file, a *javascripts*, *sass* and *stylesheets* folders.
Next I run **Scout.app** to watch *myProyect2* and appear this message:

```
LoadError on line 1038 of org/jruby/RubyKernel.java: no such file to load -- bootstrap-sass
/Applications/Scout.app/Contents/Resources/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/data.rb:161:in ´require'
```

If I watch *myProyect2* in Terminal with `$ compass watch .` doesn't appear error messages... but I want to understand why doesn't work Bootstrap projects in Scout.

**My versions**
*Scout 0.7.1*
*Bootstrap Affix v3.2.0*
*Compass 0.12.6 (Alnilam)*
*Sass 3.2.19 (Media Mark)*

**Image**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zM5Ax.png

---

**Releated questions:**
[compass failing to load singularitygs gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17562369/compass-failing-to-load-singularitygs-gem])

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else